# Integrals and Distributions

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

In a course "mathematical physics" we just encountered distribution, we covered the topic distribution in about 4 hours, after the lectures i think i understood it but when i look at the exercises i realise i don't understand anything at all...

Consider a test function $\phi \in C^{\infty}_{[0,1]}$ and a function $f$ continous in $[0,1].$ The plus distribution $[\frac{f(x)}{1-x}]_{+}$ is defined as

$$T_{[\frac{f(x)}{1-x}]_{+}}[\phi] = \int^1_0 dx\frac{f(x)}{1-x}(\phi(x)-\phi(1))$$

which implies $$[\frac{f(x)}{1-x}]_{+}=\frac{f(x)}{1-x}-\delta(x-1)\int^1_0dt\frac{f(t)}{1-t}$$

Now i'm supposed to compute the integral $$I=\int^1_0dx\frac{x^2+3}{(1-x)_{+}}$$

I think we can say that we can rewrite the whole thing:

$$I=\int^1_0dx\frac{x^2+3}{(1-x)_{+}}=\frac{x^2+3}{1-x}_{[+]}=\frac{x^2+3}{1-x}-\delta(x-1)\int^1_0dt\frac{t^2+3}{1-t}$$

But then I don't know what to do about $\delta(x-1)$. And this just feels weird. Can someone give me a hand?

EDIT: Based on the comment of @JeanMarie, I try again

\begin{align}
I & = \int^1_0dx\frac{x^2+3}{(1-x)_{+}} \\
 & = \frac{x^2+3}{1-x}_{[+]} \\ 
 & = \frac{x^2+3}{1-x}-\delta(x-1)\int^1_0dt\frac{t^2+3}{1-t} \\
 & = (\frac{(1-x)^2}{1-x}-\frac{2(1-x)}{1-x})-\int^1_0 \delta(x-1)\frac{(1-t)^2}{1-t}-\int^1_0 \delta(x-1)\frac{2(1-t}{1-t} \\ 
 & =-(x+1)-\int^1_0 \delta(x-1)(1-t)-\int^1_0 \delta(x-1)2
\end{align}

That's what I've got so far, i know how to evaluate those integrals with delta function inside, but they have different variables, what should one do about that?

Comment: Your computation should be eased by the fact that $x^2+3=(1-x)^2-2(1-x)$

Comment: @jeanmarie but what would one do with the delta part. Can one take it back into the integral? Then it becomes a normal integral with delta inside ?

Comment: First thing: you cannot separate the integral and put one part with a Dirac delta, because $f(x)/(1-x)$ is not locally integrable. You have to keep $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(1)$ together!

Comment: @JeanMarie, your formula as an error, the left-hand side is positive while the right-hand side is $0$ when $x=1$ ...

Comment: @LL3.14 I'm sorry which part do you mean?

Comment: The second equation ;)

Comment: @LL3.14 that is the definition i was given...

Comment: My bad: the correct decomposition is $x^2+3=(1-x)^2-2(1-x)+4$

Comment: No, I am talking about the equation after "which implies"

Comment: @ll3.14 That part is the definition I was given...

Comment: No, while it is true that $\langle \delta(x-1), \phi\rangle = \phi(1)$, and so if $K$ is a locally integrable function, with your notations $$[K(x)\,f(x)]_+ = K(x)\,f(x) - \delta(x-1)\,\int_0^1 K f$$this is not true in your case since $1/(1-x)$ is not integrable and so $\int K f$ is infinite ... and this is the reason for the additional term with $\phi(1)$, as even if $\int  \frac{f(x)\,\phi(x)}{1-x}\,\mathrm d x$ is infinite, the quantity
$$\int  \frac{f(x)\,(\phi(x)-\phi(1))}{1-x}\,\mathrm d x$$ is still well defined. You can just not split the integral as a difference of two terms.